# How do I test this function?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, python-unittest

I have this function:

```
# spark already defined somewhere as:
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("App").getOrCreate()

def read_data(spark):
    query = "SELECT * FROM table"
    pandas_df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
    return spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
```

To test it:

```
from unittest import mock

@mock.patch("pandas.read_sql")
@mock.patch("pyspark.sql.SparkSession", autospec=True)
def test_read_data(spark_session, pandas_read_sql):
    result = read_data(spark_session)
    assert == ???
```

In what way should I test this that makes sense? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to test your function you need to mock `pandas.read_sql` only, `spark_session` cannot be mocked and you need to have an instance to properly test your function. You can create your own `pytest.fixture` to meet this requirement.

```py
from unittest.mock import patch

import pandas
import pyspark.sql
import pytest
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from your_module import read_data


@pytest.fixture
def spark_session():
    _spark_session = SparkSession.builder.appName("unit-tests").getOrCreate()
    yield _spark_session
    _spark_session.stop()


@patch("pandas.read_sql")
def test_read_data(mock_read_sql, spark_session):
    # given:
    mock_read_sql.return_value = pandas.DataFrame(
        [(1, "row1"), (2, "row2")], columns=["id", "column1"]
    )

    # when:
    spark_df = read_data(spark_session)

    # then:
    assert isinstance(spark_df, pyspark.sql.DataFrame)
```

You can do much more assertions and check whether created dataframe has proper schema and contains values you expect.

Tip: You should look at spark sql capabilities, because you probably don't need to use pandas to query your database.

Comment: Where is ```mock_read_sql``` defined?

Comment: It's defined by decorator `@patch("pandas.read_sql")`